# Using A Delete Keyword With Arrays C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

So with another addition to my program, I have decided to include a function where you can remove all information from `myCourses[10]`. The newest code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct Course
{
    string name;
    double grade;
    int block;
};

Course enter_course()
{
    Course foo;

    cout << "What is the name of the course you wish to enter? (Use this format: ExampleFormat)\n";
    cin >> foo.name;
    cout << "What block is " << foo.name << " ?\n";
    cin >> foo.block;
    cout << "What is your current grade as a percent?\n";
    cin >> foo.grade;

    return foo;
}

void display_courses(Course courseList[10], int courseCount)
{
    for (int i=0; i<courseCount; i++){
        cout << i+1 << "\t" << courseList[i].name 
             << "\t\tBlock: " << courseList[i].block
             << "\tGrade: " << courseList[i].grade << "%" << endl;
    }
}

double get_gpa(Course courseList[10], int courseCount)
{
    double gradePoints;
    double total = 0.0;
    for (int i=0; i<courseCount; i++){
        if (courseList[i].grade < 100){
            gradePoints = 4;
        } 
        if (courseList[i].grade < 90){
            gradePoints = 3;
        }
        if (courseList[i].grade < 80){
            gradePoints = 2;
        }
        if (courseList[i].grade < 70){
            gradePoints = 1;
        }
        if (courseList[i].grade < 60){
            gradePoints = 0;
        }
        total += gradePoints;
    }

    return total*1.0/courseCount;

}

void display_options()
{
    cout << "1. Exit\n";
    cout << "2. Enter a Course\n"; 
    cout << "3. Display Courses\n";
    cout << "4. Display GPA\n";
    cout << "5. Request a text file output\n";
    cout << "6. Delete Grades\n";

    cout << "\n\n";
}

int main()
{
    bool exit=0;
    int option;
    int courseCount=0;
    Course myCourses[10]; //nobody should ever take more than 10 courses! 

    while (exit == 0)
    {
        cout << "GradeBook 2.0\n";
        display_options();
        cout << "Enter a command.\n";
        cin >> option;

        switch (option)
        {
            case 1: 
                exit = 1;
                break;
            case 2:
                myCourses[courseCount] = enter_course();
                courseCount++;
                break;
            case 3:
                display_courses(myCourses, courseCount);
                break;
            case 4:
                cout << get_gpa(myCourses, courseCount) << endl;
                break;
            case 5:
                ofstream outputFile;
                outputFile.open("userGrades.txt");
                for (int i = 0; i < courseCount; i++)
                {
                    outputFile << myCourses[i].name << " " << myCourses[i].grade << " " << myCourses[i].block << endl;
                }
                outputFile.close();
                cout << "Grades saved to file!" << endl;
                break;
            case 6:
                cout << "Removing data...\n";
                delete[] myCourses;
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, I receive the following errors:
error C2360: initialization of 'outputFile' is skipped by 'case' label (Line 114)
IntelliSense: transfer of control bypasses initialization of: variable "outputFile" (declared at line 105) (Line 89)
warning C4154: deletion of an array expression; conversion to pointer supplied (Line 116)
Does anyone know what is wrong with having a `delete[]` keyword inside a switch block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to `delete` something that you didn't create with `new`. That is, the array `myCourses` is not dynamically allocated. You dynamically allocate something with `new` and then deallocate it with `delete`. If you don't dynamically allocate it, you just let it go out of scope.

Simply get rid of the `delete[] myCourses;` line.

You can't delete elements from an array. They exist from the moment the array is declared until it goes out of scope. If you want there to be some kind of cleared state for an element, you need to decide what that is. You could give `Course` a flag that says whether it's cleared or not, for example. However, a much better approach is to use a standard library container like `std::vector` - with this, you genuinely can remove elements from it.

Your other error is caused by attempting to declare a variable within a `switch` statement without enclosing it in its own block. You can fix that by placing curly braces around the content of `case 5:`.

Comment: I'd rather call this problem "programming by guessing". Take a bunch of syntax you've seen elsewhere and not really understood, mix it all together and pray that something functional comes out. If not, post it on SO.

Comment: @KerrekSB That's called "[cargo cult programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming)", based on stories of people who saw airplanes filled with food and supplies landing at airports and built their own replica airports, radios, and runways expecting metal birds filled with food and supplies to appear for them too.

Comment: @sftrabbit So how do I implement `std::vector`? I can't find it on my reference website.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Hm, not quite. Cargo cult programming would produce correct, but bad or pointless code. I think this one is more profound, in that the OP doesn't have a clear concept of how the language works but tries to shake it until it does something useful.

Comment: @KerrekSB The essence of cargo cult programming is that you sprinkle your code with things you saw other people use in the hopes that you will get the same effect they did. For example, if you have memory leaks, you sprinkle `delete`s in your code. If you have race conditions, you sprinkle `volatile`s and mutexes around.

Comment: @DJHead-On, You don't implement it, your standard library implementation does that for you. Here's a [good reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) on it.

Comment: @chris I meant how do I use `std::vector`

Answer (score 3):

You can't `delete` what you didn't `new`. They must correspond. You are trying to `delete` an object that was never allocated with `new`.

Comment: So is there a better keyword to place in there?

Comment: @DJHead-On The line should just disappear all together.

Comment: @sftrabbit But is there something I can write instead that will serve the intended purpose?

Comment: @DJHead-On Arrays have fixed sizes. You can't clear elements from them. Instead you should use `std::vector`. There's plenty of information about `std::vector` around on the Internet.

Comment: @sftrabbit I've looked up `std::vector`, but I can't seem to figure out how to use it.

Comment: @DJHead-On [This explains it](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/stl/vector.html). You can create a `std::vector`, add elements to it, remove elements from it, etc. More like an `ArrayList` in Java, if you're familiar with that.

Answer (score 0):

Since others already commented on the ill-advised `delete[]` let's also address the other problem: if you want to construct an object inside the block of a `switch`-statement you'll need to put it into its own block:

```
switch (option)
{
    case 5:
        {
            ofstream outputFile;
            outputFile.open("userGrades.txt");
            for (int i = 0; i < courseCount; i++)
            {
                outputFile << myCourses[i].name << " " << myCourses[i].grade << " "
                           << myCourses[i].block << endl;
            }
            outputFile.close();
            cout << "Grades saved to file!" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
```

(note the extra parenthesis around the block infolving the `std::ofstream`). Also, note that using `std::endl` unnecessarily is a source of performance problems! Unless you really mean to flush the stream use `'\n'` instead. ... and when you mean to flush the stream use `std::flush` instead of hiding it with `std::endl`.